# How to get the 'Endpoint' of a deployed 'Lambda' function in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am developing a serverless application using the **Serverless Framework**. I deployed my application using

```
$ serverless deploy
```

After deploying, I got the endpoints for my functions which look like this

```
https://ly5webovq4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/notes
```

which I did not note down. Now I need it, but could not find it. Where can I find the Endpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run

```
$ sls info
```

And you'll get all the information on the deployed endpoints and functions.